# How to test for assert in debug build, but returned value in release?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, debugging, googletest

I want to test a function:

```
#include <cassert>

int my_func(int myParam) {
    int ret = 0
    if (myParam >= 10) {
        assert(false);
        // Logger call like `qCritical << "myParam is too big. Returning 0";`
    } else {
        ret = myParam * 2;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

`assert()`s are only enabled in the debug build.
I want to write tests that will pass whether the tests were built with the debug configuration or not (I assume this is the right way? Or is it sensible to write tests only for a specific build configuration?). So with a test input of, for example, 999:

1. If built with the debug configuration the test should expect a crash (from the `assert()`).
2. But without the debug configuration the test should expect a return value of `0`.

I'm aware of `EXPECT_DEBUG_DEATH`, which only expects a crash if built with the debug configuration. But I don't see a test macro for expecting a specific return value only if built **without** the debug configuration.

Comment: are you looking for `#ifdef NDEBUG` ?

Comment: ... or `#ifndef NDEBUG` in your case

Comment: I think that is your makefile's problem ,not your code's problem. In gcc/g++,you can use assert without debug marcos by default. I think you can seal this function to 2 same functions ,one can use without interfer by marcos, the other by reverse.

Comment: Presumably instead of `if (myParam < 10)` you mean `if (myParam >= 10)`;
otherwise the `assert` will never fire.

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, I think I must resort to this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others mentioned above, how about just using `NDEBUG` pre-processor directive? `NDEBUG` disables standard C assertions.

You could do it like

```
#ifdef NDEBUG
TEST_F(FooTest, DISABLED_MyFuncAbortsOnInputBigger10)
#else
TEST_F(FooTest, MyFuncAbortsOnInputBigger10)
#endif
{
    // ...
    EXPECT_DEATH( /* .. */ );
}

#ifdef NDEBUG
TEST_F(FooTest, MyFuncLogsInvalidInput)
#else
TEST_F(FooTest, DISABLED_MyFuncLogsInvalidInput)
#endif
{
    // ...
}
```

This way, your death test is disabled when you compile and run your test suite in release mode. In debug mode, the death test is active.

The `DISABLED_` prefix in the test name allows you to disable a test but keep compiling the test code. You can read about it in the [AdvancedGuide](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#temporarily-disabling-tests).